# Calling a local JavaScript method in an Ajax response callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I call the local JavaScript function `fn` within an ajax request? Using jQuery I am creating a link element that when clicked, will load a web resource and in its success callback a local method should be called:

```
$('body').append('<a onclick=\'$.ajax({' +
    'url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net",' +
    'context: document.body,' +
    'success: function(){$("body").append("</br>callback");fn();}});\'>CLICK ME</a>');

function fn() {
    $('body').append('</br>fn');
}
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/jzWUA/1/

Instead of `fn` being printed, the error log tells me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fn is not defined

(Using latest Chrome).

**Edit:**

As the commentors underline, treat this question as a research question. It's not ment to be used in any productive application.

Comment: That's a horrible way to attach events.

Comment: +1 while I agree that I would cry if I see this in a production application (or any application), I find this interesting.

Comment: I understand your disgust of this code snippet. The background is the following: I am modifying the websites of my mail provider (GMX) after is has been loaded using the dotjs plugin. Since that website hasn't adopted the Ajax paradigm and every single action forces a page refresh, I try (just for fun) to add some dynamic behavior that prevents from reloading the page all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't put Javascript code in string literals.

If you do this the proper way by adding an event handler, it will work fine:

```
$('<a>Click!</a>').appendTo('body').click(function() { fn(); })
```

Comment: Indeed, your suggestion it's much more adeguate.